# How can I get center offsets of a screen in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am using a stack to pan a text using the *[Offset](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/Offset-class.html)* and *[Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html)* widgets. I want to get the offset of the center. I tried

```
offset = Offset(screenWidth/2, screenHeight/2);
```

But this is not working. Is there another way possible to get the center coordinates/offset?

Comment: use `LayoutBuilder` as a parent - it passes `BoxConstraints constraints` parameter in the `builder` that you can use

Comment: make this will help you https://www.raywenderlich.com/25237210-building-a-drawing-app-in-flutter

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As [pskink commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888776/how-can-i-get-center-offsets-of-a-screen-in-flutter#comment125320023_70888776), *use LayoutBuilder as a parent*; and [Jared Anderton's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888776/how-can-i-get-center-offsets-of-a-screen-in-flutter/70888985#70888985) is quite OK, but it will calculate the *Scaffold* body, without considering other properties, like *appBar*. Also [Hrvoje Čukman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70888776/how-can-i-get-center-offsets-of-a-screen-in-flutter/70890387#70890387) meets your requirement.

Another thing can be done just using `Stack(alignment: Alignment.center`. It will align unaligned children.

The parent widget is [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html).

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constraints) {
      Offset centerOffset =
          Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
      return Scaffold(
```

Another option is getting [`windowSize`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/dart-ui-library.html) from `dart:ui`.

```dart
final Size windowSize = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).size;
late Offset screenOffset =
   Offset(windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height / 2);
```

```dart
class CenterOffset extends StatelessWidget {
  const CenterOffset({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final Size windowSize = MediaQueryData.fromWindow(window).size;
    late Offset screenOffset =
        Offset(windowSize.width / 2, windowSize.height / 2);
    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        Offset centerOffset =
            Offset(constraints.maxWidth / 2, constraints.maxHeight / 2);
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(),
            body: LayoutBuilder(
              builder: (context, chConstraints) {
                Offset bodyBasedCenter = Offset(
                    chConstraints.maxWidth / 2, chConstraints.maxHeight / 2);
                return Center(
                  child: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      Text("window based center $screenOffset"),
                      Text("Parent based center $centerOffset"),
                      Text("body   based center $bodyBasedCenter"),
                    ],
                  ),
                );
              },
            ));
      },
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: MediaQuery was exactly what I was looking for. I only needed the center of the widget not the center of the screen, so I used `final Size windowSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;`

Comment: The first code snippet appears to be incomplete.

Comment: @PeterMortensen 1st two part is just what can be used to solve the issue, last one is test-widget where I've included both

Answer (score 2):

Here is a sample implementation of the `LayoutBuilder`

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Center Coords")),
  body: LayoutBuilder(builder: (context, BoxConstraints constraints) =>
      Center(child:
        Column(
          children: [
            Text("center width: ${constraints.maxWidth/2}"),
            Text("center height: ${constraints.maxHeight/2}"),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 2):

If your goal is to center your widget, the easier way is to use the [Align](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget instead of the [Positioned](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Positioned-class.html) widget

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Container(),
);
```